# Getting error Type 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method addEventListener through a reference with static type

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I moved my code from my Application to a separate AS class file and now I'm getting the following errors:

```
1061: Call to a possibly undefined method addEventListener through a reference with static type Class.

1180: Call to a possibly undefined method addEventListener.
```

.

```
package managers {


    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;

    public class RemoteManager extends EventDispatcher {


        public function RemoteManager() {

        }


        public static function init(clearCache:Boolean = false):void {

            addEventListener(SETTINGS_CHANGE, settingChangeHandler);
            addEventListener(ITEMS_UPDATED, itemsUpdatedHandler);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```
addEventListener(SETTINGS_CHANGE, settingChangeHandler);
```

evaluates to

```
this.addEventListener(SETTINGS_CHANGE, settingChangeHandler);
```

There is no `this` in a static method, since it's designed to function without an instance. Furthermore, you cannot attach an event listener and dispatch events from a static class.

Either change your function declaration to

```
public function init(clearCache:Boolean = false):void
```

Or implement a singleton pattern to kinda get a *"static class, that dispatches events"*.

[Singleton with event management.](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showpost.php3?p=846641&postcount=2)

Answer (score 1):

You have declared your method init as static , so all you can use into this one is static field, static method, no object that belong to the instance.

Remove the static from the function or try to implements a singleton if it what you are after.

here a quick really simple one :

```
 public class RemoteManager extends EventDispatcher {
    private static var _instance:RemoteManager;
    public function static getInstance():RemoteManager{
     if (_instance == null) _instance=new RemoteManager();
     return _instance;
    }

    public function RemoteManager() {
      if (_instance != null) throw new Error("use getInstance");
    }


    public static function init(clearCache:Boolean = false):void {
        getInstance().addEventListener(SETTINGS_CHANGE, settingChangeHandler);
        getInstance().addEventListener(ITEMS_UPDATED, itemsUpdatedHandler);
    }
}

// use it
RemoteManager.init();
```