# How do i control my character class with a button in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I'm pretty new to as3, so I'm sorry if my language isn't very proffesional.

I'm making a game, and it's working so far, except for the controls. 
I want the character to be controlled by three buttons, I have on the stage.

When i started making my game, I had all my scripting on the first frame,
and the control part worked fine, but then i found out that i had to export the character, the enemies and the stage to action script (making them into classes), to get the enemy spawning i wanted.

How do i control my character class with the buttons now??

I tried to export the buttons to action script also, but I can't seem to reference between the character class and the button class.

In my character class i wrote:

```
LeftButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICKED, moveLeft)

function moveLeft(m:MouseEvent) {
trace("Click")
}
```

But then it said: 1061 call to a possibly undefined method decode through a reference with static type class... So it doesn't know what LeftButton is.

In my button class i wrote:

```
addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICKED, moveLeft)

function moveLeft(m:MouseEvent) {
trace("Click");
CharacterMC = CharacterMC + 5;
}
```

This worked when i didn't add the character part, when i added the character part it did the same thing

I also tried in my stage class.. but nothing seems to work, and i can't find anything on this particular issue..

Do anyone have an answer or
can anyone point me in some direction??
thanks..

Comment: where did you put your event listener? do you have added_to_stage event? to handle if the object has been added to stage or not

Comment: **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826131/getting-error-type-1061-call-to-a-possibly-undefined-method-addeventlistener-th)** might help?

Comment: @MGol I put the event listener inside the button class, if that is what you mean, and I am able to press it and trace ("click"), but I can't get the character class to move when i click it.

Comment: I dont know why you're not being told the obvious.. `CharacterMC.x = CharacterMC.x + 5;` or the better/shorter version.. `CharacterMC.x += 5;` using the `+=` just means "add on top (increment) of _variables_ current value"

Answer (score 0):

Oh well, I found out myself, had to try a lot things, maybe I was just being a noob at the beginning:

I added this code to my main.as:

```
var lb = new MoveLeftButton();
addChild(lb);
lb.x = 68.25;
lb.y = 759.10;
lb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, moveLeft)

function moveLeft(ev:MouseEvent):void
{
trace("button Clicked");
character.x = character.x - 100;
}
```

Comment: Doh.. I comment then see you got it anyway. You can also do it like this: `character.x -= 100;`